# How is template used here to create a fixed size map?

Tags: c++, templates, std

```
typedef map<int, double> SparseRow;
template <int N> struct SparseMatrix
{
map<int, SparseRow> data;
};


const int N = 5;
SparseMatrix<N> sparseMat;
```

I am confused as how the template type N is used here? can anybody explain why it makes this map fixed size?

/////////////////////////////////////

**edit**

this is a print function and a call to it

```
print(sparseMat);

    template <int N>
void print(SparseMatrix<N>& sm)
{
SparseRow sr;
SparseRow::const iterator it;
for (int row = 0; row < N; row++)
{
SparseRow sr = sm.data[row];
// Now iterate over row
for (it = sm.data[row].begin(); it != sm.data[row].end();
it++)
{
cout << (*it).second << ", ";
}
cout << endl;
}
}
```

How does the value N get passed to the function, if its not in the function call? I am confused as to how an instance of the SparseMatrix will save a value like suppose 5?

Comment: The parameter N isn't used in the code you've shown.

Comment: then how is the map made fixed size?

Comment: What makes you think that it is?

Comment: N is part of the template's type. It gets baked in at compile time, not passed anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can anybody explain why it makes this map fixed size?

It doesn’t – there is no such thing as a fixed-size map in the standard library. The non-type template argument `N` isn’t actually used inside the template you’ve shown us. It *could* conceivably be used to ensure that the map never grows over 5 elements but there is no direct benefit of making it a template argument, it could just as well be a normal variable.

In the *added code* (after the edit) you can see that `N` is used as the size of the internal map – obviously that only works if each `row` of the matrix has previously been correctly initialised. But again, nothing in this code indicates why the author chose to make the size a template argument rather than a data member.

Comment: so why has the author mentioned it?

Comment: You should ask the author. Nothing you've shown indicates it's fixed-size, except your own statements.

Comment: @user494461 Impossible to say without the full definition. However, I suspect that there isn’t a hard and fast reason for it – maybe the author wanted to artificially restrict the size so they can later change the implementation to a statically-sized custom map implementation.

Comment: Well, `const` map *is* fixed size ;P

Comment: @user494461 the size, or the fact that `SparseMatrix<5>` and `SparseMatrix<6>` are different types could be used elsewhere in the code.